# Visual Studio 2022 & CMake: Calling a custom script to build x86/x64 easily

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I currently call CMake recursively using `ExternalProject_Add` to build the x86 and x64 components in one go for a specific toolset. This generally works, but I've encountered multiple issues with it and want to get away from it. I've tried some different solutions but they all have some issues.

1. I've tested a script that uses the value of `CurrentProjectSetting` from `.vs/ProjectSettings.json` and `ActiveBuildPreset` from `.vs/VSWorkspaceState.json` to configure/build/clean the active configure/build preset and its counterpart (x86 and x64). This script works perfectly fine on its own. However, if the cache becomes out of date for some reason and I run the super configure, VS doesn't seem to detect that the cache has actually been updated and Intellisense becomes broken. I have to then do a normal configure to get VS happy again for the active configure & build preset.
2. I've tried setting the "cmakeExecutable" value for each configure preset to a .bat file that runs what is passed to it for the active preset along with its counterpart. However, VS replaces the name of my bat file with cmake.exe. It will have the full path the script folder, but it will just be cmake.exe, not "super_build.bat". I have no idea about this one.

Is there something special I can do to get VS happy when I update the cache outside of it?

#### tasks.vs.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "SuperConfigure",
      "appliesTo": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "type": "launch",
      "command": "perl",
      "args": [ "tools\\super_build.pl", "--action=configure" ]
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "SuperBuild",
      "appliesTo": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "type": "launch",
      "command": "perl",
      "args": [ "tools\\super_build.pl", "--action=build" ]
    },
    {
      "taskLabel": "SuperClean",
      "appliesTo": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "type": "launch",
      "command": "perl",
      "args": [ "tools\\super_build.pl", "--action=clean" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### CMakePresets.json

This is a cut down version. I also have presets for ClangCL and Debug/Release etc:

```json
{
  "version": 4,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 24,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "Default-Win32",
      "hidden": true,
      "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "Win32",
        "strategy": "set"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Default-x64",
      "hidden": true,
      "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x64",
        "strategy": "set"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "displayName": "Win32",
      "description": "Build the Win32 components.",
      "inherits": "Default-Win32",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}"
    },
    {
      "name": "x64",
      "displayName": "x64",
      "description": "Build the x64 components.",
      "inherits": "Default-x64",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}"
    },
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "Default-Debug",
      "hidden": true,
      "description": "Builds with --config Debug",
      "configuration": "Debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "Win32-Debug",
      "displayName": "Debug",
      "inherits": "Default-Debug",
      "configurePreset": "Win32"
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "displayName": "Debug",
      "inherits": "Default-Debug",
      "configurePreset": "x64"
    }
  ]
}
```